# Long delay when using Modernizr/yepnope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr, yepnope

I'm starting to use Modernizr for my front-end projects these days and just realized something that bugs me.

(Demo link after code snippets)

But first, here's what's before my `<body>`:

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/loader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here's my `loader` script (removed some lines for brevity):

```
Modernizr.load([

    // jQuery
    {
        load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js',
        complete: function () {
            if (!window.jQuery) {
                Modernizr.load('js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');
            }
        }
    }

    // Slick (slideshow)
    ,{
        load: '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.9/slick.min.js',
        complete: function() {
            if (!window.jQuery.fn.slick) {
                Modernizr.load('slick/slick.min.js');
            }
        }
    }

    // Main script
    ,'js/script.min.js'
]);
```

Demo link: http://toki-woki.net/lab/transbal/

I can see the page load and, almost a second after that, my slideshow initializer (wrapped in a `$()` call) kicks in. That delay is fairly long and unaesthetic, which is what I want to fix.

I've looked at the Network tab in Chrome and see my Modernizr-loaded scripts are first loaded as images (thus, not executing) and then added as `script` tags and, eventually, executing. That would explain the delay, because jQuery would be executed late (after the DOMContentLoaded event) and the `$()` call would fire after that.

[image: Network tab screenshot]

Some questions:

1. Is that how Modernizr/yepnope works?
2. Is it possible to reduce that delay?
3. What event is used by Modernizr/yepnope to determine when to inject `script` tags? Looks like it's `load` but that seems like a strange choice to me...

I've tried not using `Modernizr.load` at all and reference my script just before the `</body>` tag and it works perfectly (no slideshow size jumping) but it is harder and heavier to maintain...

Got tips?
Thanks!

Comment: The script loading facility in Modernizr is not designed for performance. You'd be better off loading your scripts conventionally (that is, with `<script>` tags) or with RequireJS.